# wpf page not editable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem trying to develop a WPF page. I have a window with a WPF Frame, when the window is loaded i use MainFrame.Navigate(new page object). The only problem is i can not press any button or use a textbox. Any idea, how can i solve this?

here is the code of my wpf window:

```
<Window x:Class="ViewLayer.Forms.Win_LoginCloseable"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Win_LoginCloseable" Height="477" Width="501" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="180*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="164*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="35*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="3"  Name="Rect_Main" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="17" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,12,7" Name="tb_remainding" Text="" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Button Content="Cerrrar" Grid.Row="1" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btn_cancel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="173" Click="btn_cancel_Click" Background="#FFC70000" Margin="114,0,114,5" />
            <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" IsHitTestVisible="False" NavigationUIVisibility="Automatic" />
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF797979" Height="95" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Una vez identificado, luego de 90 segundos de inactividad el sistema cerrará su sesión automaticamente" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="None" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,100,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the constructor of the window

```
private Win_LoginCloseable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Pages = new List<Page>();
            this.Pages.AddRange(new Page[]{
                    new MagneticCardPage(),
                    new UserInputPage()
                });

        }
```

here when i load the form:

```
public void LoadForm(int Index = 0)
{
this.MainFrame.Navigate(this.Pages[Index]);
this.ShowDialog();
}
```

i repeat, in a page i have textboxs and buttons. But when i try to use them or clicked i can. The events are not getting to the pages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code where you are handling the events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I Figure out the solution of the problem.

here:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" IsHitTestVisible="False" NavigationUIVisibility="Automatic" />
```

i replace it with:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" IsManipulationEnabled="True" />
```

and it works well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the **constructor** is wrong. **It should be marked public, instead of private.**

The constructor will always call InitializeComponent, but it can't function normally if your constructor is marked as private. Therefore, the control will be displayed BUT the event handle will not be executed, because event handler code is available inside InitializeComponent, and I'm sure it won't be executed.

Change this:

```
private Win_LoginCloseable()         
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Pages = new List<Page>();
    this.Pages.AddRange(new Page[]{                     
        new MagneticCardPage(),                     
        new UserInputPage() });          
}
```

Into this:

```
public Win_LoginCloseable()         
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Pages = new List<Page>();
    this.Pages.AddRange(new Page[]{                     
        new MagneticCardPage(),                     
        new UserInputPage() });          
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! The constructor is private because i probe make the window singleton. Then i change the constructor to public but i works the same as before.